# Uploading file as part of the form in Django Rest Framework return 415

Tags: angularjs, django, rest

I am trying to submit a form that has an attachment from angularJS to Django backend.
I am trying to work my way through the documentation, but I still cannot get pass the 415 error.

This is my backend code so far:

```
class TGBuildDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
  queryset = TGBuild.objects.all()
  serializer_class = TGBuildSerializer
  permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
  parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,)

  def perform_update(self, serializer):
    print "Hello"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 415 Unsupported Media Type, maybe adding FileUploadParser to parser_classes helps?

Comment: I think the problem with using FileUploadParser, it will ignore my any other inputs. This is the error I get when doing so:
{"owner":["This field is required."],"reviewer":["This field is required."],"status":["This field is required."],"purpose":["This field is required."],"wo_id":["This field is required."]}

Comment: Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: In the front end, I add this:    function updateTG(upload) {
      console.log(upload);
      TGBuild.update($scope.tgbuild).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
    } But it returns null. In the html I have:     <button ng-if="!isNew" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="updateTG(tgbuild.upload)">Update</button>
and in the form I have:           <div class="col-sm-9"><input class="form-control" type="file" ng-model="tgbuild.upload" accept="application/zip"></div>

Comment: @LauriElias I don't have it. Let me try to add it.

Comment: @LauriElias I added     <button ng-if="!isNew" type="button" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="updateTG()">Update</button>
But it still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. I do not even use the FormParser, MultiPartParser, nor FileParser on the serializer.

This is how I do it. I mostly follow the file upload angularjs tutorial:
https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

At the template html:

```
    <div class="col-sm-9"><input class="form-control" type="file" file-model="tgbuild.upload"></div>
```

Then I created directive file:

```
angular.module('ctdgroup').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind("change", function(){
           scope.$apply(function(){
             modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
           });
        });
     }
};   
}]);
```

Then, finally in my create method in service.js:

```
function create(tgbuild) {
  tgbuild.status = OPEN;
  tgbuild.deployment_date = moment(tgbuild.deployment_date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');

  var fd = new FormData();
  for (var key in tgbuild){
    fd.append(key, tgbuild[key]);
  }

  return $http.post('/tgbuilds/', fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  });

}
```